# ZF2: validation of attached file

Tags: php, file-upload, zend-framework2

I want to do the simple action of uploading files (multiple). The attached files I get from client like:

```
var data = new FormData();
_.some(this.collection.models, function(model, index) {
      data.append('file_'+index, model.get('_FILE'));
}
```

On the server-side I try to perform validation process through Http adapter. Suppose that a single file is attached:

```
$_files = $this->params()->fromFiles();

print_r($_files[0]);

$extension = new \Zend\Validator\File\Extension('jpeg,jpg');
$adapter = new \Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http(); 

$adapter->addValidator($extension);

if($extension->isValid($_files[0]))
{
    echo 'valid';
} else {
    $messages = $extension->getMessages();
    echo implode("\n", $messages);
}

if($adapter->isValid($_files[0])) 
{
    echo 'valid';
} else {
    $messages = $adapter->getMessages();
    echo implode("\n", $messages);
}
```

...and method $adapter->isValid() isn't valid. But $extension->isValid() works fine.

```
Array ( 
    [name] => untitled_test.png 
    [type] => image/png 
    [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpRPlV8G 
    [error] => 0 [size] => 398 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

For file upload there is a special `Zend\Validator\File\UploadFile` validator. I think you should consider using this class. You can find more information about it **[here in the documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.validator.file.html#uploadfile)**.

It is automatically used in the `FileInput` class which is a special input type for uploaded files found in the `$_FILES` array.

Read more on how to use/implement this **[in the official ZF2 documentation here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.input-filter.file-input.html#zend-input-filter-file-input)**.

Answer (score 0):

When I create instance of \Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http() class constructor loads all posted files ($_FILES) by default.
Here is my complete solution. Maybe someone will be useful.

```
/**
 * Upload multiple images
 * 
 * @return JsonModel
 */
public function imageAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $uploadStatus = [];

    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) 
    {
        $models = $this->params()->fromPost('models');

        $adapter = new \Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http();

        $size       = new \Zend\Validator\File\Size(['min' => '100B', 'max' => '10MB','useByteString' => true]);
        $extension  = new \Zend\Validator\File\Extension(['jpg','gif','png','jpeg'], true);

        if (extension_loaded('fileinfo')) 
        {
            $adapter->setValidators([new \Zend\Validator\File\IsImage()]);
        }

        $adapter->setValidators([$size, $extension]);

        foreach($models as $index => $rawModel)
        {
            /**
             * Parse JSON model
             */
            $model = json_decode($rawModel,true);
            /**
             * Get full filename
             */
            $_file = $adapter->getFileInfo('file_'.$model['index'])['file_'.$model['index']]['name'];

            if (!$adapter->isValid($_file)) 
            {
                foreach ($adapter->getMessages() as $key => $msg) 
                {
                    $uploadStatus['errorFiles'][] = $_file.' '.strtolower($msg);
                }
            }

            $filename = $this->appPlugin()->generateFilename($model['name']);
            $filepath = $this->appPlugin()->getImageDestination();

            $adapter->addFilter('File\Rename', ['target' => $filepath.$filename, 'overwrite' => true]);

            if (!$adapter->receive($_file)) 
            {
                $uploadStatus["errorFiles"][] = $_file.' was not uploaded';
            } else {
                $uploadStatus["successFiles"][] = $_file.' was successfully uploaded';
            }
        }
    }

    return new JsonModel(['uploadStatus'=>$uploadStatus]);
}
```

Full example is here http://learnzf2.sitrun-tech.com/learn-zf2-ajax-image-gallery. Thanks community.